# The exclude of the rsync doesn't exclude according to the pattern?

Tags: macos, rsync

When using the rsync via

```
rsync --delete --exclude=".._*" -vahE ~/Desktop /Volumes/BLUE/Sync/Desktop
```

command, as a result I'm getting this error

```
...
Desktop/Relax/quotes/._Screenshot 2020-12-29 at 09.11.03.png
Desktop/Relax/quotes/._Screenshot 2020-12-29 at 09.11.30.png
copyfile(.._Desktop.gTnUtf,./Desktop, COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:45

sent 620.36K bytes  received 798 bytes  248.46K bytes/sec
total size is 221.46M  speedup is 356.53
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I tried the exclude pattern to get rid of `.._Desktop.gTnUtf,./Desktop`, but without success.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread helped ...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238808)

So the solution I found is to install newer version of rsync what I did through brew.

Only one issue is that brew will not replace system package, but this is not a problem.

I ran `brew info rsync` and got the location of the command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the option `-E` for rsync of Mac OS. If you use that option the `rsync` version that comes with Mac OS X doesn't allow you to exclude dotfiles. Without `-E`, the exclusion should work

```
rsync --delete --exclude=".._*" -vah ~/Desktop /Volumes/BLUE/Sync/Desktop
```

Comment: Thanks to fill the gap in my knowledge :)